# Extending two related queries on same model in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Consider a Django model that forms a connection between two other model instances:

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Meeting(models.Model):
    user_a = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='a_meetings')
    user_b = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='b_meetings')
```

Now suppose you want to define a function that returns all of a `User`s meetings, regardless of if he is side `a` or `b`. The naive implementation would be:

```
class User(models.Model):
    @property
    def meetings(self):
        return list(self.a_meetings.all()) + list(self.b_meetings.all())
```

What's the 'right' way to have this function return the matching `QuerySet` instead of a list? Bonus points for an elegant solution that doesn't use an ugly `Q` query ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Qs are inevitable here.

The main principle with these things is always to start from the model you actually want to get: so since you want meetings, start there.

```
return Meeting.objects.filter(Q(user_a=self) | Q(user_b=self))
```

Comment: Yep this is my current solution, I thought something nicer existed, but oh well. Thanks!